# How to prevent double arguments in bash script

Tags: bash

I have this code and wanna make sure that when someone runs "myscript.sh -h -h" or "myscript.sh -hh" it doesnt echo WOW 2 times.

```
while getopts ":h-:" option; do
    case $option in
      h )
          echo "WOW"
      ;;
    esac
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a variable to check if `-h` has been processed already:

```
h=
while getopts "h" option; do
    case $option in
      h )
          [ "$h" ] || echo "WOW"
          h=1
      ;;
    esac
done
```

The line `[ "$h" ] || echo "WOW"` will only run the echo statement if the condition `[ "$h" ]` is false and that condition is false only if the variable h is empty.

Comment: and could you tell me what does this do?
EXTENSION="${i#*=}"
i know it takes all the characters from the variable $i after character =.
But I dont understand how does the #* work, what it is

Comment: That is an example of _prefix removal_.  The general form is `${variable#pattern}` which removes the shortest match to the glob `pattern` from the beginning of `variable`.  In your case, `pattern` consists of `*` which matches zero or more of any character, and `=` which matches just `=`.  See `man bash` for more info.

Comment: _Suffix removal_ is `${variable%pattern}`.  See `man bash` for details.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you don't take any action *while* parsing command-line arguments. Instead, use them to set state that you can check once you've parsed them all.

```
do_wow=0   # By default, don't echo "wow"

while getopts ":h-:" option; do
    case $option in
      h ) # do_wow will equal 1 whether you use -h
          # once, twice, or 100 times.
          do_wow=1
      ;;
    esac
done

if [[ $do_wow -eq 1 ]]; then
   echo "wow"
fi
```